# alter strings of importet component

Tags: vue.js

I use a third part date-picker component

https://github.com/damienroche/vue-mj-daterangepicker

The component have a 'locale' prop which can take 4 or 5 different localeCodes to change its language.
Non of the codes are the language that i want. Is there anyway that i could somehow access and manipulate the string inside the date-picker component that you see below?

[image]

Comment: Actually, no. There isn't any way. You'd have to fork the library and update the component as the only truly supported locales are defined in `const locales = {` unfortunately.

Comment: If the component doesn't provide means to import custom locales, there won't be any reasonable way to do that from your side without forking that component directly.